# Generate random string in salesforce

Tags: apex

I need to generate a random string of 100 char where 0 (zero) should come 20 times.

I am using below code to generate random string, how can I leverage to get the solution, or if anyone have any other solution.

```
Integer len = 100;
final String chars = '0123456789';
String randStr = '';
while (randStr.length() < len) {
   Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
  randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you generating a non-random random string? (If it contains exactly 20 zeros, it is *not* random). This sounds like an x-y problem to me.

Comment: I'm only asking because I'm curious: Is this an actual requirement that 0 should come exactly 20 times? Not 19 and not 21? Because it can be done... but much like we learned from Jurassic Park and most uses of Regex, it probably SHOULD NOT be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem, it's not clear what your asking.. There is multiple ways to do this  Your code wouldwork above if you track the number of 0's..

```
String chars = '0123456789';
String randStr = '';

for(Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(i < 20)
    {
        randStr += '0';
    }
    else
    {
        randStr += String.valueOf(Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length()));
    }
}
```